# Cmake issue when linking against OpenCV that is built from source

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I cloned, compiled and installed the master branch of OpenCV:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/some/non-system-path \ 
         -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo \
         -DCMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH=/some/non-system-path

make
make install
```

Usual stuff, except that I'm installing it in a user path. To test it, I tried to run the following "hello world" example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
int main(int argc, char** argv )
{
    if ( argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("usage: DisplayImage.out <Image_Path>\n");
        return -1;
    }
    Mat image;
    image = imread( argv[1], 1 );
    if ( !image.data )
    {
        printf("No image data \n");
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow("Display Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow("Display Image", image);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

with the following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( DisplayImage )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_executable( DisplayImage main.cpp )
target_link_libraries( DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Note that this is exact example from OpenCV. It fails with the following:

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/main.cpp.o
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'opencv_calib3d-NOTFOUND', needed by 'DisplayImage'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Looking in the `/some/non-system-path/lib` there exists `libopencv_calib3d.so` pointing to `libopencv_calib3d.so.3.3.1`.

I assumed that this might be `link_directories` issue, however, setting it didn't solve the problem either. As for `${OpenCV_LIBS}` I printed it and I got:

```
message(STATUS "OpenCV_LIBS = ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
-- OpenCV_LIBS = opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_dnn;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_shape;opencv_stitching;opencv_superres;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_videostab;opencv_viz
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hm. Could you `grep OpenCV CMakeCache.txt`? Because I don't see where CMake got `opencv_calib3d-NOTFOUND` from. Also, what happens if you add `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/some/non-system-path` to the CMake call? (Just to be sure, I know CMake is supposed to pick up dependencies in `INSTALL_PREFIX`.)

Comment: @DevSolar: I guess `opencv_calib3d-NOTFOUND` is a "location" property of `opencv_calib3d` *IMPORTED* library. It seems, something wrong with `find_package(OpenCV)` script (it shouldn't set `-NOTFOUND` properties) or with OpenCV installation in total. I agree that checking `CMakeCache.txt` for OpenCV entries could be helpfull. [Isn't grepping should be **case-insensetive**? In `opencv_calib3d-NOTFOUND` the first part is the **precise** name of the variable.]

Comment: @DevSolar, for the "hello world" cmake, I call it with proper prefix_path so to locate opencv. Grepping in CMakeCache of hello world [**1**](https://pastebin.com/YyR9QP71). Grepping cache of OpenCV build [**2**](https://pastebin.com/Kfn9crZh)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when was building OpenCV on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2019 using CMake. `x64-Debug` configuration was built successfully, but `x64-Release` had `opencv_calib3d-NOTFOUND` error.

A quote from alalek [comment](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/10597#issuecomment-357947551):

> OpenCV supported builds are Debug and Release only. Other build configurations are not supported at all and proper compiler flags are not applied.

I noticed that CMakeSettings.json had `RelWithDebInfo` configuration type for `x64-Release`. So I changed it to `Release` configuration type and that fixed the issue.

P. S. Also possible solution is described [here](https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv/issues/193#issuecomment-351154785), but I did not try it.